# mod_rewrite ignored/not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am having some issues with mod_rewrite on a new Apache dev PC I have set up.

I have enabled mod_rewrite as an apache module and editted the conf file to allow rewriting, however when I try creating rewrites nothing happens.  The htaccess file is being invoked to some extent as I am able to cause a 500 error by putting invalid syntax in the file.

Can someone spot the stupd mistake I am making or suggest something else that I am missing that needs enabling?

httpd.conf:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^content/css/([a-z0-9])/$  /min/?g=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^1.php$ 2.php
```

Comment: Can you show an example URL that fails?

Comment: Localhost/content/css/1/ just 404's

localhost/1.php doesn't display 2.php's content.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have

```
<Directory />
     ...
     Deny from all
</Directory>
```

in httpd.conf?
You should see 403 error is this case.